# Django query for all items from today

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like to query and get all the pages created today. Here are my models:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='pages', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='', blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

and I am trying to query like this:

```
todays_pages = Page.objects.filter(date_created = datetime.date.today())
```

except that it doesn't work unless I change the field to a datefield and not a datetime field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. I am not trying to deal with timezones or anything so this works fine.

```
today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

todays_pages = Page.objects.filter(date_created__gt = today)[:25]
yesterdays_pages = Page.objects.filter(date_created__gt = yesterday, date_created__lt = today)[:25]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try like this:

```
todays_pages = Page.objects.filter(date_created__gte = datetime.date.now().replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now()
current_day = Page.objects.filter(date_created__date=datetime.date(today))\
    .values('category','name')
```

this worked for me

got idea from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#week

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.datetime.now()` is time zone unaware. You may want to use `django.utils.timezone` to convert.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the objects based on a time. The way that I would do it is something like this...

```
today = datetime.date.today()
todays_pages = Page.objects.filter(date_created__range=[today,])
```

I have not tried this code specifically but this is my best guess on how to get all posts that have the current calendar day.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it should be easy, but it is in fact a non-trivial problem, due primarily to timezones. Your `DateTimeField` stores a particular point in time. Which date that point in time occurred on could be different in different timezones - the exact same point in time could be Wednesday morning in Berlin but Tuesday night in San Francisco.

Given a date you want to query for and a timezone, the strategy is this:

1) Construct a datetime for "start of that day in that timezone" and a datetime for "end of that day in that timezone".

2) Query for pages with a `date_created` between your start and end datetimes.

In some code I wrote recently, I have a `combine` function for combining a date, a time, and a timezone into a datetime:

```
from django.utils import timezone
import pytz

def combine(adate, atime, tz=None, is_dst=None):
    """Turn a date and a time into a datetime in given timezone (or default).

    The ``is_dst`` argument controls the handling of ambiguous datetimes
    (e.g. during fall DST changeover), and nonexistent datetimes (e.g. during
    spring DST changeover). If it is ``None`` (the default), these cases will
    return ``None`` instead of a datetime. If it is ``True``, these cases will
    be resolved by always assuming DST, and if ``False`` by assuming no-DST.

    """
    tz = tz or timezone.get_current_timezone()
    naive = dt(adate.year, adate.month, adate.day, atime.hour, atime.minute)
    try:
        return tz.normalize(tz.localize(naive, is_dst=is_dst))
    except pytz.InvalidTimeError:
        return None
```

Then your query looks like this:

```
def get_pages_created_on_date(for_date):
    start = combine(for_date, time(0))
    end = combine(for_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1), time(0))
    return Page.objects.filter(date_created__gte=start, date_created__lt=end)
```

That version just uses the currently activated timezone (which is probably the timezone configured in your Django settings file, unless you've done some additional work to activate a local timezone for the current request's user).

I'm not aware of any timezone in which the DST transition occurs at midnight, which should make this code safe against DST changeover issues. But if there is such a timezone, and you may need to handle datetimes in it, then your query function would need to pass an `is_dst` flag to `combine`.

If you're passing `today` to this query, you have to also think about how you generate your date value for `today`. Calling `datetime.date.today()` will always give you today's date in your server operating system's local timezone. This may not correspond with your Django-settings timezone, or with the currently-activated Django timezone, which will cause the query to not give correct results. For correct timezone handling, you should use a `today` function like this instead:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def today():
    return timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).date()
```

TL;DR: correct handling of dates and times is hard. Hope this helps; good luck!